# How I can to manualy add new value in carbonfields type "association" there is in field "complex" type?

Tags: php, wordpress

My init code

```
Field::make( 'complex', 'fieldname', 'Name' )
    ->add_fields( array(
        Field::make('association', 'item', 'Name')
        ->set_types([['type'=>'post','post_type'=>'courses']])
        ->set_max( 1 ),
        Field::make('date_time', 'expiration', 'Title')          
    ) )
```

I need to add new value in 'complex' field and after in 'item' field
I use this fields in user profile (wordpress) and I found this guide https://github.com/htmlburger/carbon-fields/issues/697 but it did not work for user :(

Answer (score 0):

So, I opened https://github.com/htmlburger/carbon-fields/blob/46e9b60c30061e869fca66227e50dfc009afe194/core/functions.php End found super function carbon_set_user_meta that is not in the documentation ((

Working code

```
carbon_set_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'fieldname', [
[
    "item" => [
        [
            'value' => 'post:courses:56',
            'id' => 56,
            'type' => 'post',
            'subtype' => 'courses'
        ]
    ]
]
]);
```

- 56 - wordpress post id
- courses - custom post type